How to split a cell text by delimiter, do a lookup into given data set using the split cell text, and print in another sheet
Below is a small sample of the data set I am working with.

I figured out I can use TEXTSPLIT(D2,,",") to split a comma delimited cell and get the individual AHNs in a vertical format but I want to create a formula that I can apply to the entire data set and get something like below in a separate sheet.

The issue as you've probably figured out is for a cell with multiple comma separated values, the split cell spills down multiple rows. I could manually go through the list and copy and paste vertically into a new sheet but I am curious if there is a better way using excel formulas/macros.

Here is one way using Excel Formulas if using MS365 then the following should work, also it can be accomplished using Power Query


=LET(
     α, A2:B7,
     DROP(REDUCE(0,SEQUENCE(ROWS(α)),LAMBDA(φ,δ,
     VSTACK(φ,IF({1,0},INDEX(α,δ,0),TEXTSPLIT(INDEX(α,δ,2),,", "))))),1))


However, using POWER QUERY will be the easiest and neat approach.


To perform the above task, follow the steps:

First convert the source range into a table and name it accordingly, for this example I have named it as Table1



Next, open a blank query from Data Tab --> Get & Transform Data --> Get Data --> From Other Sources --> Blank Query



The above lets the Power Query window opens, now from Home Tab --> Advanced Editor --> And paste the following M-Code by removing whatever you see, and press Done


let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    #"Split Column by Delimiter" = Table.ExpandListColumn(Table.TransformColumns(Source, {{"Agreement AHN", Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter(",", QuoteStyle.Csv), let itemType = (type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true] in type {itemType}}}), "Agreement AHN")
in
    #"Split Column by Delimiter"



Lastly, to import it back to Excel --> Click on Close & Load or Close & Load To --> The first one which clicked shall create a New Sheet with the required output while the latter will prompt a window asking you where to place the result.




Using Split function to split the data in Col B

Microsoft documentation:

Split function


Range.Resize property (Excel)

Sub Demo()
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    Dim arrData, rngData As Range
    Dim arrRes(), iR As Long, aTxt
    Set rngData = ActiveSheet.Range("A1").CurrentRegion
    arrData = rngData.Value
    For i = LBound(arrData) To UBound(arrData)
        aTxt = Split(arrData(i, 2), ",")
        For j = LBound(aTxt) To UBound(aTxt)
            iR = iR + 1
            ReDim Preserve arrRes(1, 1 To iR)
            arrRes(0, iR) = arrData(i, 1)
            arrRes(1, iR) = Trim(aTxt(j))
        Next j
    Next i
    Sheets.Add
    Range("A1").Resize(iR, 2).Value = Application.Transpose(arrRes)
End Sub

